# How to build the nfcpy source code to a python module?

Tags: python, nfc

I want to use the [nfcpy](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~stephen-tiedemann/nfcpy/trunk/files) lib to read/write NFC tags. But I just get some source code of python.

How can I buide it to a python module that I can add `import nfc` to my program?

Comment: The source code is the module.

Comment: @Snakes and Coffee , How to add this module to my Python environment? I just use Ruby. I'm a novice of Python.

Comment: either add it to `site-packages` (for windows, something else for *nix), or put it in the directory you are working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is explained how you can make a module of your python code:
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

your module (here should be your python code):

```
# this goes in mystuff.py
def apple():
    print "I AM APPLES!"
```

access it that way:

```
import mystuff
mystuff.apple()
```